# Trouble passing table data through stored procedure

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to pass this table through a `sp_execute_remote`, and I'm only getting a blank table, and I'm not sure why this would be happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[membershipSP]
AS

DECLARE @memberships MembershipsTable;

INSERT INTO @memberships 
SELECT * FROM memberships;

execute sp_execute_remote
    N'RemoteData',
    N'select * from @memberships',
    N'@memberships MembershipsTable READONLY';

GO
```

EDIT* - Just to be clear, what I mean by this, is i'm getting all the columns but no data rows. Is this not allowed by `sp_execute_remote`?

Comment: My best guess is that you have to have declared a user-defined table type on both the local remote machine with the same name and schema. But even then, I've never tried to pass table-valued parameters to `Execute`, `sp_execute_sql` or `sp_execute_remote`. The doc doesn't say there are limits on parameter types, but I'd be surprised/thrilled to find out that you can use 'em.

Comment: @Clay I did declare the user-defined table type on both databases. They are both identical and so I assumed this would work.

Comment: Then I suspect you're out of luck. You might go old-school and serialize your table into a string that you parse on th' other side :-(

Comment: In fact, you could probably `for xml` or `for json` it very simply and pick it up on the other side.